# Facebook PHP sdk 4 add hashtag to the photo message

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the following code to upload an image with the Facebook sdk.

```
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

if($session) {

  try {

    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
        'source' => new CURLFile('path/to/image', 'image/jpg'),
        'message' => 'Photo text #hashtag'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();


  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    var_dump($e);

  }   
}
```

I would like to add a hashtag in the photo message which the user can click, when he sees the post on his facebook feed. 
Is this possible?

Comment: is the message user generated? because it has to be, according to the platform policy.

Comment: @luschn The message is given by the user in a previous step of the application

Comment: that is alright then, but you can only use it 1:1 - so if facebook does not automatically turn it into a clickable hashtag, i guess it is not possible to force it.